# libgdx touchDown called just once

Tags: libgdx

I'm new to LibGdx, and have problem with input handling.

My player needs to shoot bullets whenever touch is down.
But it seems that this method is called just once...

And then user have to click again to shoot another bullet.

I want always to shoot bullets while click is down...

Is there a way to handle this use case?

Comment: Which specific method?  (There are multiple ways of getting touch events in Libgdx.)

Comment: touchDown method in InputProcessor. When I click...it's called only once...no matter if I hold click or just release it quickly. I need to detect when user holds click. There is method touchDragged...but it's called only when I hold click and move cursor...Than way I can't detect when user just holds click and holds cursors still in the same place...Hope you understand the idea...It's pretty much simple, can't believe there isn't way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've succeeded to work this out, without pooling concept.

I have custom InputProccesor, int I've used similar logic like P.T. mentioned.
I touchDown I start thread that shoots bullets and do some calculation, because I access to some methods from Renderer class I've to use

```
   Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        // process the result, e.g. add it to an Array<Result> field of the ApplicationListener.
        shootBullet(screenX, screenY);
        }
    });
```

To avoid OpenGL context exception.

In touchUp method I cancel shooting thread.

Tnx for idea!

Comment: Nice!  Good to have two useful solutions for a problem.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Look into ["polling" on the touch input](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputPolling), instead of getting [Input events](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputEvent).  So, in your render or update method, use something like this:

```
 boolean activeTouch = false;

 if (Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
    if (activeTouch) {
       // continuing a touch ...
    } else {
       // starting a new touch ..
       activeTouch = true;
    }     
 } else {
    activeTouch = false;
 }
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sence...but I need to get X and Y coordinates of the touch, so I can't do some calculations of rotation and angle. How can I get X and Y coordinates whit this approach?

Comment: Follow the "polling on touch input" link, and you'll see you can also read the current touch coordinates (`Gdx.input.getX(0)`, etc).  Similar for button and key presses ...

Answer (score 2):

I have use [Continuous Input handle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

This is done by setting a flag to your actor eg:

```
public class Player{
  private boolean firing = false;
  private final Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/player.png"));

  public void updateFiring(){
    if (firing){
        // Firing code here
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Firing bullets");
    }
  }

  public void setFiring(boolean f){
    this.firing  = f;
  }

  Texture getTexture(){
    return this.texture;
  }

}
```

Now in my Application class implementing InputProcessor

```
@Override
public void create() {
    player= new Player();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sprite = new Sprite(player.getTexture());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    // Update the firing state of the player
    enemyJet.updateFiring();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    switch (keycode){
        case Input.Keys.SPACE:
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Start firing");
            player.setFiring(true);

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    switch (keycode){
        case Input.Keys.SPACE:
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Stop firing");
            player.setFiring(false);

    }
    return true;
}
```

Done