# LibGDX key pressed/held

Tags: keyboard, libgdx

How to distinguish when a key is only pressed or held. Using this code:

```
Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)
```

returns true every time the button is held, but how to get only 'one time' press?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316146/libgdx-touchdown-called-just-once (that one wants touch events, not keyboard but the ideas are the same).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: [Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(int key)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#isKeyJustPressed-int-)