# LibGDX Orthographic camera: Make borders black instead of white (java)

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, border, orthographic

I am using the LibGDX orthographic camera class to handle different screen sizes and it works pretty well for me. The only issue I have is the border around the screen when the device doesn't stretch to scale.

I don't mind a border that much, the only thing that bothers me is the color of the border. I think it would look much nicer if it was black instead of white. Any way to change that?

**Also I posted another question about android touch handling that was never answered. If someone could answer that, that would be great. I don't want to have to ask it again, I don't want to seem spammy. [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755340/android-surfaceview-better-way-to-tell-if-screen-is-touched-java)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your camera view is smaller than screen you probably just need to change clear color of GL.

```
glClearColor(r, g, b, a);    
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Thanks! You both gave me the right solution I just wanted you to have the rep. Funny thing is that I litterally just did that but using `glClearColor(1,1,1,1);` thinking that rgb of 1,1,1 gives black but its actually white. Complete noob mistake on my part. I don't really like how libgdx uses rgb though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

Black clear screen. Thats all you need.